# Prisma failed queries don't return proper errors

Tags: node.js, error-handling, orm, prisma, prisma2

In my Prisma/express backend, I have this schema:

`schema.prisma` :

```js
model user {
  id              Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String
  last_name       String
  role            role     @relation(fields: [role_id], references: [id])
  role_id         Int
  birth_date      DateTime
  created_at      DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at      DateTime @updatedAt
}

model role {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  description String
  user        user[]
}
```

---

When I try to insert data that is not valid(wrong type of data for instance), I get the full error on the console but I can never retrieve it on the code so that I can handle the errors according to error codes that Prisma has on its docs. Whenever I log or return on my requests responses, this is what I get:

```json
{ "clientVersion": "3.8.1" }
```

---

This is where I execute the query that I expected to get the proper error as per the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference):

`user.controller.ts` :

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { Request, Response } from "express";

const mockData = {
    name: "test",
    last_name: "test_lastname",
    birth_date: "28/07/1999", // invalid Date
    role_id: "1" // invalid type, should be Int
}

module.exports = {
  post: async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    const prisma: any = new PrismaClient();
    try {
      const result = await prisma.user.create({
        data: mockData,
      });

      res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.json(err);
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably need to read this part of the docs about proper error handling: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/handling-exceptions-and-errors

Just to quote it, you need to check error with `instanceof` call to determine what type of error it is, what properties it has, and handle it accordingly.

For example `PrismaClientKnownRequestError` has `code` property, but `PrismaClientValidationError` does not and so on.

Example:

```
try {
  await client.user.create({ data: { email: 'alreadyexisting@mail.com' } })
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
    // The .code property can be accessed in a type-safe manner
    if (e.code === 'P2002') {
      console.log(
        'There is a unique constraint violation, a new user cannot be created with this email'
      )
    }
  }
  throw e
}
```

Regarding your code, we can't really know what `res.json(err);` does under the hood, hard to tell why it only returns `clientVersion`, but just `console.log` should call `.toString()` method on the error object and you should get much more info about it, not just `clientVersion`

Comment: `console.log` doesn't have a different output, it's the same as `res.json(err)`. Regarding the error instances, you're right, `PrismaClientValidationError` doesn't have an error code, but it should come with a `message` property, as stated [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference). This error message would be way better than `clientVersion`

Comment: So you actually tried to `console.log(e.message)` and it was `undefined`? Or what do you mean? I've just tested it and it works as described in the docs

Comment: Yes, if I `console.log(err)`, I get the JSON I put on the question,  and `console.log(err.message)` is `undefined`

Comment: Docs says that error handling is incomplete for Mongo at this moment. Are you using it by chance? Maybe that's why some fields are missing, I haven't used it with Prisma yet, so can't tell. Or what db and what version of db are you using? If this is not the case then it seems like a bug and I suggest you to create an issue on Prisma Github page https://github.com/prisma/prisma, although they will probably ask for minimal reproduction example.

Comment: I'm using it with Postgres, I just found this github [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10141). And yes, I think I'll have to create an issue, since my problem is quite similar but happens on client queries rather than raw queries